# Emacs: how to define 'bookmark' variables of directories

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I use Emacs and ESS for R programming and usually I work in a few specific folders. Due to the configuration of my working environment, the folders that I work on is usually "very deep" in each folder structure, i.e., I need to specify several subfolders before reaching the directory that I work in:

```
/Desktop/SUB1/SUB2/SUB3/SUB4...
```

It's tedious and I have to repeatedly use `CTR+X` `CTR+F` to find the files, even I only need to work in a few places. I am wondering, is there any possibility that allow me to define a few variables that stores the common locations that I work on, and when I need to find any script, I only need to invoke something like:

```
$SHORTCUT/Script.R
```

This would be a function like a bookmark in the Linux window manager. I understand there is a global setting environment that allows you to set the default directory. However, that will only make the work a bit easier for one folder. It's an improvement, but still not good enough if I am working on several projects simultaneously.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `M-x bookmark-set`. You could use file-registers as well. See `C-h f set-register`

Comment: In addition to setting bookmarks to files or directories, you can define an OS environment variable and use completion. IOW, you can use exactly `$SHORTCUT/Script.R`. `TAB` completes input that starts with `$SHORTCUT` by expanding the environment variable. However, bookmarks are generally quicker (less to type) and more flexible.

Comment: @Drew. Thank you and I was able to create a system environment. However, Emacs has to be started on a command line to let the system environment work. Is there anyway you could recommend that make it automatically load the system environments? The option `(getenv var)` somehow does not work well and only support one specific variable.

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Environment.html). How you set environment variables outside Emacs (which Emacs can then access) depends on your OS. And see node [File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Names.html) for information about expansion of environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a few options. I have 2 in store for you bookmarks and file-registers
if you execute the following command

`(set-register ?a '(file . "~/.emacs"))`

Then execute `C-x r j a` or `M-x jump-to-register a` you will jump to your .emacs file. I encourage you to read the docs on registers they are quite handy.

The second one is bookmark. You can bookmark files or directory by using `C-x r m` in the buffer on interest. Don't forget to save the bookmarks or they will disappear next time you restart emacs. `M-x bookmark save`

*update*
A third option would be the use of keychords package which you can find on melpa

```
(defun open-this  ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/.emacs") )

(require 'key-chord)
(key-chord-mode 1)
(key-chord-define-global "=-"  'open-this)
```

then by pressing `=-` simultaneously or fast enough you would go to the .emacs file. A nice feature is that you could use local mode as well so the same key-chord would do different things depending on your mode.

Comment: (set-register ?a '(file . "~/.emacs"))

Comment: The bookmark works great. One question: I noticed that you could also use register for positions. Does the register name support multiple characters, e.g., instead of `r`, maybe i could use `crr`?

Comment: no as far as I know resgisters don't not support multiple characters but it is case sensitive so that leave you with plenty of options. Another alternative is the use of `key-chords` to open files. But you need to install the package from melpa. see update

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have done in the past:

```
(defun jea-open-deep-file (arg)
  (interactive "sWhich File?: ")
  (cond
   ((string= "1" arg) (find-file "~/.emacs"))
   ((string= "2" arg) (find-file "/Users/jamesanderson/code/python/aws/comprehend/README.md"))
   ((string= "3" arg) (find-file "~/some/other/file/somewhere/else.el"))
   (t (message "unknown choice"))))
(global-set-key [(f7)] 'jea-open-deep-file)
```

so, what I happening here?  There is a function called:  "jea-open-deep-file" that can open any file with "find-file."  If you want to try it, you can put in in your ".emacs" file, or the *scratch* buffer to just try it once.  Once you edit the find-file calls to point to the files you want to open, you can evaluate the buffer (there are several ways to do this, the easiest for this discussion is: <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> then "eval-buffer" without the quotes in the bottom area).

How to use?  In this case I have mapped the function to the <kbd>F7</kbd> key.  Choose one that you don't already use.  So, once installed with eval-buffer, I can go:

- <kbd>F7</kbd>
- It prompts me with "Which File?"
- I type 1, 2 or 3 and hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd>
- emacs opens the file

I don't have access to a windows machine right now but, you may need to alter the paths slightly, like: `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Aspell\\bin\\aspell.exe"` this with extra <kbd>\\</kbd> escapes.

Any time you want to add a file to jea-open-deep-file, you will need t re-evaluate the function (it seems a bit weird at first, but, that is how you "edit the editor while you are editing" which is really nice to not have to reload the whole emacs app.).

Edit:

If you want to jump to a particular line, please try:

```
(defun jea-open-file-goto-line (fname line)
  (progn
    (find-file fname)
    (goto-char 0)
    (forward-line line)))

(defun jea-open-deep-file (arg)
  (interactive "sWhich File-Line?: ")
  (let* ((split (split-string arg "-"))
         (file (car split))
         (line (string-to-number (cadr split))))
    (cond
     ((string= "a" file) (jea-open-file-goto-line "~/.emacs" line))
     ((string= "b" file) (jea-open-file-goto-line "/Users/jamesanderson/code/python/aws/comprehend/README.md" line))
     ((string= "c" file) (jea-open-file-goto-line "~/some/other/file/somewhere/else.el" line))
     (t (message "unknown choice")))))

(global-set-key [(f7)] 'jea-open-deep-file)
```

when prompted type "b-13" (without the quotes) if you want to go to the 13th line of the file marked "b"

Comment: Thank you James. One question: does this function support positions, instead of files? Usually there are multiple files I work on in a specific folder and it will be more flexible that way.

Comment: I added a version that jumps to a line.  Is that what you want?  Or have I misunderstood.  If you want to jump to directories, I would suggest the fantastic org-mode

Comment: there is also a bookmark system (that I never use, but, is probably good)

Comment: It is directories that I mean. Sorry for the confusion. I do not know if org-mode works well with R coding but will give it a try later!

Comment: try making a file like "mylinks.org" to start org mode.  Then add `[[file+emacs:/Users/name/logs/tasks/l/learn/][learn]]` org mode should make it a link that just says "learn".  when you click you should open that directory that precedes it.  org-mode is really worth spending  some time learning.